# How to use sbt-assembly?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm quite new to Scala and sbt and would like to create a fat jar files which includes all the dependency libraries. It looks like the original sbt does not do that and I have to user something like sbt-assembly. However I can't quite figure out how should I install and use it. Can someone elaborate on it for me?

Answer (score 3):

Drop this into project/plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.13.0")
```

That should let you run `sbt assembly` now.  Then you can solve merge conflicts in your build.sbt or Build.scala.

Comment: but where is this project/plugins.sbt?

Comment: You can create a new `<project-home>/project/plugins.sbt` file, if  there does not yet exist one.